# How can I call a C function from a Unix shell script?

Tags: c, shell

I have some C code and I make a library (shared object to be more specific) of it. If I want to call a particular function of this code in a shell script, how would I do it? I don't want to modify the C code by the way, just test it using shell.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a simple program that is a wrapper around the C function.
2. Call the program from the shell.

Say you have a function

```
void foo(int arg1, char* arg2);
```

The `main` function of the wrapper program would be:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   // Add the necessary checks to make sure
   // you have the required arguments.
   int arg1 = atoi(argv[1]);
   int arg2 = argv[2]);
   foo(arg1, arg2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in functionality for this in the common shells like `bash`, `sh` or `csh`. The only way is to write an executable wrapping this function (or functions) and call it from your script. Moreover your executable may receive arguments telling which function to invoke.

Comment: However, some shells (`zsh` and probably *some recent* versions of `bash`...) accept plugins.

Comment: I have seen something about KornShell and this functionality, but haven't figured it out completely

Comment: But you'll need to code the plugin according to shell-specific conventions...